# parse XML in python without newline

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath

here is the xml file
http://www.diveintopython3.net/examples/feed.xml

my python code:

```
from lxml import etree
def lxml():
    tree = etree.parse('feed.xml')
    NSMAP = {"nn":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
    test = tree.xpath('//nn:category[@term="html"]/..',namespaces=NSMAP)
    for elem in tree.iter():
        print(elem.tag,'\t',elem.attrib)
    print('-------------------------------')
    test1 = tree.xpath('//nn:category',namespaces=NSMAP)
    print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    for node in test1:
        test2 = node.xpath('./../nn:summary',namespaces=NSMAP) # return a list
        print(test2.xpath('normalize-space(.)'))
    print('*****************************************')
    test3 = tree.xpath('//text()[normalize-space(.)]')# [normalize-space()] only remove the heading and tailing
    print(test3)
```

the output is:..

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
['Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds\n    bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far\n    would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip;\n    On dialup.']
['Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds\n    bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far\n    would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip;\n    On dialup.']
['Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds\n    bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far\n    would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip;\n    On dialup.']
['The accessibility orthodoxy does not permit people to\n      question the value of features that are rarely useful and rarely used.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
['These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.']
*****************************************
['\n  ', 'dive into mark', '\n  ', 'currently between addictions', '\n  ', 'tag:diveintomark.org,2001-07-29:/', '\n  ', '2009-03-27T21:56:07Z', '\n  ', '\n  ', '\n  ', '\n    ', '\n      ', 'Mark', '\n      ', 'http://diveintomark.org/', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'Dive into history, 2009 edition', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'tag:diveintomark.org,2009-03-27:/archives/20090327172042', '\n    ', '2009-03-27T21:56:07Z', '\n    ', '2009-03-27T17:20:42Z', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n  ', 'Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds\n    bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far\n    would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip;\n    On dialup.', '\n  ', '\n  ', '\n    ', '\n      ', 'Mark', '\n      ', 'http://diveintomark.org/', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'Accessibility is a harsh mistress', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'tag:diveintomark.org,2009-03-21:/archives/20090321200928', '\n    ', '2009-03-22T01:05:37Z', '\n    ', '2009-03-21T20:09:28Z', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'The accessibility orthodoxy does not permit people to\n      question the value of features that are rarely useful and rarely used.', '\n  ', '\n  ', '\n    ', '\n      ', 'Mark', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'A gentle introduction to video encoding, part 1: container formats', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'tag:diveintomark.org,2008-12-18:/archives/20081218155422', '\n    ', '2009-01-11T19:39:22Z', '\n    ', '2008-12-18T15:54:22Z', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'These notes will eventually become part of a\n      tech talk on video encoding.', '\n  ', '\n']..
```

My question is why there are so many '\n'.   how to delete them?

additional question is how to directly query the tag of a text, such as make to get the node of "Mark" ( the child of entry's text.

Thanks so much

Comment: Please, don't ever post codes as image. Post it as texts, and format it properly (highlight/select the text -> click on `{}`). Thanks

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry for the bad style since I am beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*My question is why there are so many '\n'. how to delete them?*"

Every whitespace in the XML would be selected by your XPath. And nicely formatted XML usually contains plenty of newlines and spaces. For example, in the XML below there are two empty text nodes that will be selected by `//text()` i.e one between `<root>` and `<foo>`, and another one between `</foo>` and `</root>` :

```
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

You can use `//text()[normalize-space()]` to avoid selecting empty text nodes in the first place.

> "*additional question is how to directly query the tag of a text, such as make to get the node of "Mark" ( the child of entry's text.*"

```
your_text_node.getparent().tag
```

The above should get parent element of the text node referenced by variable `your_text_node`, and then return the element's tag name.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is an escape sequence.

You can check the page source and find that `bloated` is at the beginning of a new line.

To delete them, you can use [`string.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) or [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).